# Get Particular value from Ajax Result

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

My code works fine . Accessing data using Ajax. From that result i want to show a particular value in label. When i use the below code the value displays correctly

```
var i = parseInt(doc.d.length);
$("#<%=lblPresnet.ClientID %>").text(doc.d[5].PresentDays);
```

But i need to change my code as

```
var i = parseInt(doc.d.length);
$("#<%=lblPresnet.ClientID %>").text(doc.d[i].PresentDays);
```

here i found an error that

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PresentDays' of undefined
```

I dont have an idea why it so
My Ajax Code

```
success: function (doc) {
console.log(doc);
var my_events = [];
if (!doc.result) {
$.each(doc.d, function (index, elem) {
    my_events.push({
        id: elem.EventName,
        title: elem.EventName,
        start: elem.StartDate,
        image: elem.ImageType,
    });
    var i = parseInt(doc.d.length);
    $("#<%=lblPresnet.ClientID %>").text(doc.d[5].PresentDays);
}); callback(my_events);
}
}
```

Console Result

```
{d: Array(6)}d: Array(6)0: {EventID: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", EventName: "Present", StartDate: "2017-08-01", PresentDays: 1, AbsentDays: 0, …}1: {EventID: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", EventName: "Present", StartDate: "2017-08-02", PresentDays: 2, AbsentDays: 0, …}2: {EventID: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", EventName: "Present", StartDate: "2017-08-03", PresentDays: 3, AbsentDays: 0, …}3: {EventID: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", EventName: "Present", StartDate: "2017-08-04", PresentDays: 4, AbsentDays: 0, …}4: {EventID: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", EventName: "Present", StartDate: "2017-08-07", PresentDays: 5, AbsentDays: 0, …}5: {EventID: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000", EventName: "Present", StartDate: "2017-08-08", PresentDays: 6, AbsentDays: 0, …}length: 6__proto__: Array(0)__proto__: Object
```

Is their any solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doc.d's length is 6, but its indexes go from 0 to 5... I'm guessing you should change those lines to

```
var i = parseInt(doc.d.length - 1);
$("#<%=lblPresnet.ClientID %>").text(doc.d[i].PresentDays);
```

Comment: @D le . Thanks I forget about the index count.

Comment: happy to help :)